# Offset on query results

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery, offset

I am trying to compare weekly results. To be more specific, I want to get the difference week after week.

First I would like to show how the result should look like:

```
CalendarWeek     currently      previous_week      delta
2016-01          200            
2016-02          210            200                 10
2016-03          205            210                 -5
2016-04          230            205                 25
...
```

I got a solution but it is pretty slow.

Currently I am doing it like this:

```
SELECT CalendarWeek, cur_value - prev_value AS delta
FROM  
    (SELECT CalendarWeek, COUNT(Change_ID) AS cur_value
     FROM Changes
     WHERE ...
     GROUP BY CalendarWeek) AS cur_week
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT CalendarWeek, COUNT(Change_ID) AS prev_value
     FROM Changes
     WHERE ...
     GROUP BY CalendarWeek) AS prev_week
ON cur_week.CalendarWeek = prev_week.CalendarWeek + 1
```

My problem is, that running the subqueries takes a lot of time (I did simplify them for this showcase). The `SELECT` with the `COUNT()` runs 45 sec. each = 1,5 min. I think there should be a more appropriate solution. I just need the prev_value to be 1 row shifted or with an offset of 1 row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use variables instead:

```
SELECT w.*,
       (CASE WHEN (@pcv := @prev_value) = NULL THEN NULL       -- never happens
             WHEN (@prev_value := cur_value) = NULL THEN NULL  -- never happens
             ELSE @pcv
        END) as prev_value
FROM (SELECT CalendarWeek, COUNT(Change_ID) AS cur_value
      FROM Changes
      WHERE ...
      GROUP BY CalendarWeek AS cur_week
     ) w CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT @prev_value := -1) params
ORDER BY CalendarWeek;
```

You can then use an additional subquery to calculate ratios and differences.

Note:  The logic for assigning the previous value is a three step process:  (1) cache the previous previous value in a variable, (2) reassign the previous value, and (3) then use the cached value.

MySQL does not guarantee the order of execution of expressions in a `SELECT`, so this all has to happen in a single expression (hence the `= NULL`, which is never true).  Almost all other databases support `lag()` for this purpose, which makes the query faster and the logic simpler.

Comment: Thank you. It works properly. Really nice idea to cache the values. That´s it exactly what I was looking for! There is just one parenthesis too much ahead of the CROSS JOIN. :)